# Windows API To Access Font Tables (Kern, GPOS, etc)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, fonts

Currently Apple provides functions to access data in font tables, like [CTFontCopyTable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1510755-ctfontcopytable). I'm using it to parse information (kerning, etc) out of a font when available. Is there any similar way of pulling the same data on Windows per font?

I can see a lot of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gpos) on the windows side when it comes to these font tables, but I can't seem to find a way to pull this data per font.

Here is how I'm pulling the data in osx:

```
CTFontRef lCTFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)lNSFontName, 800.0f, NULL);
CFDataRef lKernTable = CTFontCopyTable(lCTFont, kCTFontTableKern, kCTFontTableOptionNoOptions);
CFDataRef lGPOSTable = CTFontCopyTable(lCTFont, kCTFontTableGPOS, kCTFontTableOptionNoOptions);
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/OpenTechEngine/bmfont/blob/master/source/unicode.cpp (and search for `GetFontData`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetFontData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontdata) will get the raw table data, but as other suggestions advise, you will probably want to use the system-provided text layout methods rather than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GetKerningPairs` to get kerning data and `GetCharacterPlacement` to get GPOS data.

If your real intent is to simply render some text correctly though, you might want to use [Uniscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/using-uniscribe) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IDWriteFontFace::TryGetFontTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefontface-trygetfonttable), but, like [GetFontData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontdata), you will need to parse the table.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35677063)